# Search text in range and display results in a textbox

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is working, but I want to display results from a range D2:D82 in a textbox without automatically redirecting the user to the located text.

When it comes to VBA, I am a very basic user.

```
Sub Button 1_Click()

Res = InputBox("Who are you looking for?")    
Set Rng = Worksheets("Level2").Range("B2:B82")   '<<  The Sheet Name and Range to Search

With Rng    
    Set MyChoice = .Find(What:=Res)

    If Not MyChoice Is Nothing Then    
        Application.Goto MyChoice    
    Else: GoTo ExitMyChoice

    End If

End With    
Exit Sub

ExitMyChoice:    
MsgBox "Could Not Find " & Res

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what results you want to display, however the code below may help. You don't need the `GoTo` statements. You should also use Option Explicit to force declarations of all your variables and catch mismatch errors directly in the VBA editor.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim res As Variant
    res = InputBox("Who are you looking for?")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Level2").Range("B2:B82")   '<<  The Sheet Name and Range to Search

    With rng
        Dim myChoice As Range
        Set myChoice = .Find(What:=res)
        If Not myChoice Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Found '" & res & "' at " & myChoice.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not find " & res
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer. I removed the `With` statement as you're only using it once anyway.

Comment: Hello thanks your comment. Sorry but your macros retrieve results in a textbox